# How Do I Declare a Somewhat Dynamic PHP Variable

Tags: php, variables, foreach

How do I declare a variable with part of another variable plus some text at the end like this but without the syntax error...

```
$filename = $foreachvar['base_var']'.jpg';
```

Comment: I cant imagine such question existed in SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the string concatenation operator:

```
$filename = $foreachvar['base_var'] . '.jpg';
                                    ^---
```

or, in a different way:

```
$filename = "{$foreachvar['base_var']}.jpg";
```

Comment: A suggestion to learn PHP  string operation would be more appreciated.

Comment: I would assumed if he's using `foreach`es and uploading files with `php` he would know how to concatenate.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: everyone has to start somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Using the [concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
$filename = $foreachvar['base_var'] . '.jpg';
```

You can also use the [curly syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

```
$filename = "{$foreachvar['bae_var']}.jpg";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$filename = $foreachvar['base_var'] . '.jpg';
```

That's just assigning a value to the variable, which looks like what you're trying to do.